# How to create angular project in Tizen?

Tags: angular, tizen

I would like to create a Tizen application with Angular 15, but I can't find any tutorials except for this one, which dates back to Angular 6: https://medium.com/@lahtela/writing-a-tizen-watch-application-with-angular-6-cd7d788fef95

Do you have a tutorial to recommend

Thank you.

i want to have a tutorial